# htaccess remove .php extension, index.php AND add trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This is for basic HTML/PHP pages, no query strings, etc.. I have searched high and low and find resources for removing the 'index.php' from the URI, or removing '.php' and other file extensions.. and even adding a trailing slash. But, everytime I try to use them all, or use examples that I have found, I get a 500 server error.

I may pass a query string on one page, but really I just want to remove 'index.php' from the index page and have all sub pages without the file extension. So, something like this:

domain.com/index.php   to   domain.com/
domain.com/page1.php   to   domain.com/page1/
domain.com/page2.php   to   domain.com/page2/
domain.com/page3.php   to   domain.com/page3/

All the examples I can find are focused on CMSs, etc.. with query strings, etc.. nothing just focusing on the base URI, which I think might be what was causing the errors i was getting.

Any help is appreciated !!
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got this from a rather helpful chap on a forum once - never fully understood it, and there is one caveat; it implies **no** trailing slash unless the request is a directory.

However, I thought it was worth posting - a guru out there may easily spot the fix!?

```
# remove .php; use THE_REQUEST to prevent infinite loops
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]

# remove index
RewriteRule (.*)index$ $1 [R=301]

# remove slash if not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]

# add .php to access file, but don't redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll give this a go and see what we can figure out.. any gurus care to add to/adjust this to include a trailing slash to all requests??

Comment: FINALLY, an answer that works.  I searched high and low.  One note, I had to add "RewriteBase /" to the beginning because my files are nested in other folders that go below the domain, and it was routing them to lower levels, which showed up in the URL.  = no good.

Comment: I too have been searching high and low for an answer to this and this is it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your htaccess file:

```
Options +MultiViews
```

But it depends on wheter it is enabled by your webserver. Also, do note that htaccess files are specific to Apache webservers, so it won't work if you're using something else.

Comment: Do you still know somebody who is not using Apache? :)

Comment: @Marco Demaio: actually... I mostly use Nginx these days. Apache has some advantages but usually you don't need all those features.