# add `.php` at the end of url using `.htaccess`

Tags: php, .htaccess

How can i add `.php` at the end of url using `.htaccess` and below is .htaccess code

### .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Enable Rewriting
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/?$ search.php?loc=$1

</IfModule>
```

### search.php

if the url is

```
search.php?loc=miami

echo "Location : " . $_GET['loc'];

output: Location : miami
```

but how can get `search.php/miami.php` in the end ?

Comment: Of course the `loc` GET parameter doesn't have .php, you would need to request search.php?loc=miami.php for that. What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Do you mean you want to turn `search/miami` into `search.php?loc=search.php/miami.php`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using mod_rewrite to hide .php from the end of URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086325/using-mod-rewrite-to-hide-php-from-the-end-of-urls) -- Albeit I'm not sure either what's being asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^search\.php/(.+)\.php$ search.php?loc=$1
```