# how to redirect a short url to a php file with parameters

Tags: php, url-rewriting

Hello here is what I am trying to do : 
if someone goes to site.com/myusername they get sent to site.com/index.php?a=profile&u=myusername

should be pretty simple if you know htaccess rewrite engine. also any good beginner tutorials for something similar ?

here is my present .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{request_filename} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{request_filename} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(([^/]*)+)(/([^/]{0,32})(/.+)?)?$ /index.php?a=$1&q=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /index.php?a=profile&u=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086325/using-mod-rewrite-to-hide-php-from-the-end-of-urls

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php you should try searching for existing posts..

Comment: Loads of other posts here and elsewhere about how to rewrite urls. Try learning to use search tools and you will find development so much easier

Comment: thank you guys im checking those links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /index.php?a=profile&u=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: hello anubhava. there is already a : RewriteCond %{request_filename} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(([^/]*)+)(/([^/]{0,32})(/.+)?)?$  index.php?a=$1&q=$3    [L] at the top that is being used. can you edit the code please? because when i added yours underneath it didnt work

Comment: Looks like you got it working. If you're still facing issues, pls provide your current .htaccess in your question (not in comments).

Comment: check please. I added it

Comment: I edited your .htaccess in your question with my suggested changes.

Answer (score 1):

If the url is as specified , you can do something like

```
if (!isset($_REQUEST['u'])) {

$x = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$y = str_replace('?', '', $x);
$z = str_replace('/', '', $y);
header("Location: ?a=profile&u=$z"); }
```

Not really a good solution though, but this was what I could think of..if you want to do it in php..

Answer (score 0):

I know you already got the answer. But i just figured it before one hour. But my system problem so only i am posting it later. 
This is also one way to do.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?a=profile&q=$1
```