# Hide index.php AND .php from URLs while using QUERY_STRING

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to be able to hide both index.php and .php from my URLs while using QUERY_STRING.

Right now, I'm successfully hiding index.php (except when accessing certain directories) with the following in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(codex|_core|admin|index\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I'm doing this because I have certain functions, such as login/logout/registration, acting as pages: example.com/login

However, I also have some static pages that wouldn't benefit from being inside one file with a bunch of PHP functions... such as example.com/terms-and-conditions.php

In the spirit of being uniform, how do I turn that URL into example.com/terms-and-conditions without breaking example.com/login? Is this even possible? I've tried adding the .php removal rewrite about the index.php removal rewrite (obviously removing the .php from index.php) to no avail.

I did try using the solution located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024631/htaccess-remove-php-extension-index-php-and-add-trailing-slash) but it broke example.com/login — I assume because the way I'm using functions/queries. Is there just something small I need to change there?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Just needed to combine the two, which seems obvious in retrospect. :)

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove .php; use THE_REQUEST to prevent infinite loops
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]

RewriteCond $1 !^(codex|_core|admin|index\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L] 

# remove slash if not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]

# add .php to access file, but don't redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
```